# Probability of no two consecutive accidents

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, independence

> One half of the customers of an insurance company are women, the other half are men. Each year the probability that a man has a car accident is $\beta$. Also, each year the probability that a woman has a car accident is $\alpha$. The probability that an **arbitrary** customer has an accident this year is $\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$.
>
> What is the probability that a randomly chosen customer doesn't have two accidents in two consecutive years?

To be clear, we are looking for the probability of the events:

year $i$ accident and year $i+1$ no accident

year $i$ no accident and year $i+1$ accident

year $i$ no accident and year $i+1$ no accident

---

Let be $A_i$ the event that an accident occurs in year $i$ and $F$ the event that a chosen customer is female. We know from the information that $P(A_i|F)=\alpha$ and $P(A_i)=\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$. We are looking for the probability
$$1-P(A_{i+1}\cap A_i\mid F)-P(A_{i+1}\cap A_i\mid F^c).$$
If I check $P(A_{i+1}\cap A_i\mid F)$ I got stuck after some manipulations (of course the same happens with $P(A_{i+1}\cap A_i\mid F^c)$):
$$
\begin{align*}
&P(A_{i+1}\cap A_i\mid F)=\frac{P(A_{i+1}\cap A_i\cap F)}{P(F)}\frac{P(A_i\cap F)}{P(A_i\cap F)}\\
&=P(A_{i+1}\mid A_i\cap F)P(A_i\mid F)=P(A_{i+1}\mid A_i\cap F)\alpha=\dots?
\end{align*}$$
We have no information about $P(A_{i+1}\mid A_i\cap F)$. Am I missing something? It seems to me that this problem can't be solved without further information!?

Comment: knowing that a customer had an accident in year one is evidence as to their gender (depending on the values of $\alpha, \beta$).  If, say, $\alpha =.0001$ and $\beta =.9999$ then, if your randomly selected individual were to have an accident, you'd be quite sure it was a man.

Comment: Note:  I think your intent is clear, but you should state explicitly that, for each specified individual, having an accident or not in any given year is independent of all other years.  I stress that this is not true for your (unspecified) individual.  In the example I gave, knowing that your person had an accident in year one dramatically increases your estimate for their risk of an accident in year two.

Comment: @lulu I am not sure if I got you right. The problem says that each year the probability of a man having an accident is $\beta$, no matter if he had an accident in the previous year or not. (Same holds in the case of a woman)

Comment: Are you sure you don't know $P(A_{i+1} \mid A_i \cap F)$? If the customer is a woman who had an accident in year $i$, what's the probability she had an accident in year $i+1$?

Comment: @aschepler, according to the information given we only know that $P(A_i\mid F)=\alpha$ for all $i\geq 1$.

Comment: Yes,  that's the independence I meant.  You don't mention that in your post.

Comment: You also just said "the probability of a man having an accident is $\beta$, no matter if he had an accident in the previous year or not". That is, $P(A_{i+1}|F^c) = P(A_{i+1}|A_i \cap F^c) = P(A_{i+1}|A_i^c \cap F_c) = \beta$

Comment: In any case, just figure out the probability that a woman has two accidents in a row, and the probability that a man has two accidents in a row and use the Law of Total Probability.